# Drawing a dfsa where L is a set of strings that contains at most 4 zeros

Tags: computer-science, automata, regular-language

For each of the following languages over alphabet $Σ = \{0, 1\}$, construct a DFSA that accepts it and a regular expression that denotes it. Prove that your automata and regular expressions are correct.
Use as few states as possible in your DFSA.

(a) $L_1 = \{x: \text{x is a set of string that contains at most 4 zeros} \}$

The regex is

$$R_1 = 1^{∗} + 1^{∗}01^{∗} + 1^{∗}01^{∗}01^{∗} + 1^*01^*01^*01^* + 1^*01^*01^*01^*01^*$$

How would I draw the dfsa for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the state transitions:

$s_0\rightarrow_1 s_0$, 
$s_0\rightarrow_0 s_1$,
$s_1\rightarrow_1 s_1$,
$s_1\rightarrow_0 s_2$,
$s_2\rightarrow_1 s_2$,
$s_2\rightarrow_0 s_3$,
$s_3\rightarrow_1 s_3$,
$s_3\rightarrow_0 s_4$,
$s_4\rightarrow_1 s_4$.

$s_0$ is the starting state and all states are final states.

Start in state $s_0$. Produce any number of 1's and then exit or read 0 and move to state $s_1$. In state $s_1$ produce any number of 1's and then exit or read 0 and move to state $s_2$, and so on.

Comment: Oh wait, this cant be done by dfsa because since it can only have one final state? If this question was changed to "x is a set of string that contains at most 1 zeros" would it be a dfsa and the regex will be $1^{*}$

Comment: Depends on the definition. Are you allowed to have $\epsilon$ transitions (empty word)?

Comment: A DFSA is a 5-tuple $M = (Q, \Sigma, \delta, s, f)$. Q is the set of states, $\Sigma$ is the input alphabet, $\delta$ is the transition, $s$ is the initial state, and $f$ is the set of accepting states. So yeah no $\epsilon$ transition

Comment: So you can have a set of accepting states, not just one.

Comment: Do you know how to explain each state? For example: $s_0: $ x has an even number of 1's. Not sure how too